# Why thread wake up is much faster when using taskset -c

Tags: linux, multithreading

I need a fast thread wake up mechanism in my use case. So I wrote a simple benchmark to see how good semaphore is.

```
#define PCALL(f)  \
  do {            \
    if (f == -1) { \
      perror(#f); \
      abort();    \
    }             \
  } while (0)

bool should_stop = false;

namespace semaphore_pthread{

struct Arg {
  sem_t start, stop;
} sems;

inline void SemInit(sem_t* sem) { PCALL(sem_init(sem, 0, 0)); }

inline void SemPost(sem_t* sem) { PCALL(sem_post(sem)); }

inline void SemWait(sem_t* sem) {
  int ret;
  do {
    ret = sem_wait(sem);
  } while (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR);
}

inline void SemDestroy(sem_t* sem) { PCALL(sem_destroy(sem));  }

void* StopperFunc(void *arg) {
  while (true) {
    SemWait(&sems.start);
    if (should_stop) break;
    SemPost(&sems.stop);
  }
  return nullptr;
}

int num_iters;
void* StarterFunc(void* arg) {
  pthread_t stopper;
  PCALL(pthread_create(&stopper, nullptr, &StopperFunc, nullptr));
  StartBenchmarkTiming();
  for (int i = 0; i < num_iters; ++i) {
    SemPost(&sems.start);
    SemWait(&sems.stop);
  }
  StopBenchmarkTiming();
  should_stop = true;
  SemPost(&sems.start);
  PCALL(pthread_join(stopper, nullptr));
  return nullptr;
}

void BM_Sem(int iters) {
  num_iters = iters;
  pthread_t starter;
  PCALL(pthread_create(&starter, nullptr, &StarterFunc, nullptr));
  PCALL(pthread_join(starter, nullptr));
}
```

It's just two threads doing ping-pong like wakes up. Each iteration includes two wakeups.

On my machine (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz), it takes around 5us per iteration. I've also tried eventfd and futex but they delivered similar results. However, if using `taskset -c 1` (all threads run in CPU 1), it takes only 1.5 us. What's the reason behind that? Is there a way to achieve the same effect programmatically instead of relying on taskset?

Comment: By same effect, do you mean 1.5us for multple CPU? or simply run every thread on CPU 1?

Comment: @LukeLee The 1.5us is after applying "taskset -c 1" on my process. So all of the threads simply run on CPU 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind your process to a single core using C instead of the `taskset` program, you can use [sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity).

As for why having both threads on one core is faster, it could be a few things:

1. Two separate cores have separate caches which need some of the same information copied across.
2. Other tasks on the system may be competing, dirtying caches.
3. Two cores may be on two separate physical processors, requiring inter-socket communication.
4. When only a single core is active, it is more likely to enter "turbo" mode on Intel processors, and never a sleep mode.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is thread level affinity setting mechanism. I can have a lot of threads in a process, but I only want subset of them pinned on a single CPU to achieve fast wake up between them and other threads can still run in parallel.

Comment: @YuanLiu: `sched_setaffinity()` actually is per-thread.  You can read about that in the man page I linked.  You can also call `pthread_setaffinity_np` which is implemented on top, if you have a `pthread_t` and want to set the affinity for it.  Either way, it's all per-thread.

Comment: One thing I want to add: the inter process interrupt can be one key reason that why thread wakeup can be expensive on multiple cores.